# What if a devil fruit user eats another alive devil fruit user(human/object)?

Tags: one-piece

It is well known if a devil fruit user eats another devil fruit they will die(with exception). And, It seems to be possible to obtain a devil fruit by eating its user (Big Mom did this). But by that logic, if someone ate a devil fruit user alive they should die to right?

[image: big mom wants to eat chopper]

eg:- When big mom was about to eat chopper if she would have done so she would have died. Right?

> [image: scared chopper]

Comment: We still don't have any insight on how DF work on the human body, but the rule is clear: Nobody can eat another DF while having a DF power beforehand. There are some exceptions but Oda still hasn't shine light on what transpired in those particular situations and we have to wait and find out.

Comment: It should be noted that it is implied that when a DF user dies, the fruit reincarnates into some nearby fruit (see the Axolotl Zoan in Punk Hazard). So it is still within the realm of possibility that Big Mom did not eat Soru Soru no Mi by eating Mother Caramel, but rather by eating some random fruit afterwards. Similarly, she wouldn't acquire the power from eating Chopper. Of course, the implication of BM acquiring the fruit by eating MC directly is almost as strong.